# Why do I need to reset required navigation properties when updating an entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using `EF5` WinForms and have a list of Invoice Entities.
I just want to update one property of the invoice, however if i dont also update the navigation property, I get an error on SaveChanges.

Why?

```
 var unpostedInvoices =   db.Invoices.Where(  o => (o.PostStatus ==
 (int)PostStatus.UnPosted) ).ToList();

    foreach (invoice inv in unpostedInvoices) 
    {
        inv.PostStatus = (int)PostStatus.Posted)
        inv.User = inv.User;    // if this line is not put in I get an error:  "The user field is required" 
    } 
    db.SaveChanges
```

Comment: are you using lazy loading or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Include method call to your initial query:

```
var unpostedInvoices =   db.Invoices.Include("User").Where((o => (o.PostStatus == (int)PostStatus.UnPosted) ).ToList();
```